# Java Sorting Date field

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a  date like `String date="June 02,2013"` etc.....

I want to Sort the Date field in Ascending and Descending

Could any one help?

I have tried this to Sort Title field

Sort by title works with follow code:

```
    public void sortByTitle() {
        Comparator<Show> comperator = new Comparator<Show>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Show object1, Show object2) {
                return object1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(
                        object2.getTitle());
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(dataFromDB, comperator);
        lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(this, dataFromDB));
    }
```

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a string to start with? If you could change your field to be a date-based field (ideally a `LocalDate` from Joda Time) it would make your life simpler all over the place.

Comment: and where is the `Date` object? You have to convert that String to a `Date` or using a lib like Joda Time that is much better than java date api

Comment: Could you help ,How to Convert that String to Date Format?

Comment: you are using the unix time stamp for that date and then sorting

Comment: are you store date in database in string manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
Collections.sort(datestring, new Comparator<String>() {
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        try {
            return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

you need to change format of date in the above code.

**UPDATED :**
Updated DateFormat check it..